# Grouping cells, adding text above or below cells & empty space in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to achieve something like the image at the bottom of the page . Specifically:

1. Add spacing between each cells (in a different group you could say.)
2. Add text above or below the cell.
3. Have empty space everywhere else with no cells.

**I want everything to look exactly like this image.**
*(Ignore the text, navigation bar, and anything inside the cells.)*

I have already tried this and came out with this image below:

[image: Example of what I have already tried]

This is my code from what I have tried:

```
let data = [["0,0", "0,1", "0,2"], ["1,0", "1,1", "1,2"]]
let headerTitles = ["Some Data 1", "KickAss"]

    // MARK: - TableView Data Source Methods

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let cellText = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = cellText

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section < headerTitles.count {
            return headerTitles[section]
        }

        return nil
    }
```

[image: Example of what I want to achieve.]

Comment: *Please don't list this post as duplicate as everything else* then please add at least a couple of these duplicates so we don't have to guess what is outdated by your definition.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: sorry I was in a rush yesterday. I’ve updated the question with my code that I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TableView State](https://medium.cobeisfresh.com/dealing-with-complex-table-views-in-ios-and-keeping-your-sanity-ff5fee1fbb83) This document will help you for tableview state. (loading, data, empty states)